# cssで属性を削除する方法を知りたいです。

Tags: css, sass

cssのスタイルで、paddingの属性を削除したいです。
最初にcssの初期化としてbase.scssを読みます。
その後にarticle.scssを読みます。
その時に、article.scssでbase.scssのulのpaddingを削除したいのですが、cssでのやり方ご存知の方いましたら教えていただきたいです。
説明が下手で申し訳ないのですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

**base.scssファイル**

```
html {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

**article.scssファイル**

```
article{
  .rich-text{
    ul{
      padding: ""; ←ここでbase.scssファイルのpaddingを削除（打ち消し）したいです。
    }
  }
}
```

**（補足）**
写真のように「・リスト(ul)」と「numberリスト（ol）」の左端を合うようにしたいです。
「numberリスト」に合わせる形になります。
写真のデベロッパーツール のpaddingの部分でチェックボタンを外すと「・リスト(ul)」が「numberリスト（ol）」の左端と合うようになりました。なのでpaddingを消したいと思っています。

**（現状）**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**（理想）**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`article .rich-text` の子孫にある `ul` 要素への `padding` プロパティの値だけ初期値を取りたいということであれば、 [`revert` 値](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/revert)を用いることで実現出来ます。[`revert` 値](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/revert)は **cascade オリジンによって動作が変わり**ます。次のコードのように、作者オリジンのスタイルへ `revert` 値が設定された場合は、もしユーザオリジンのスタイルがあればそれを使用し、なければユーザーエージェントスタイルシートを用います。

> #### § 7.3.4. Rolling Back The Cascade: the revert keyword<sup>[[1]](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#inherit-initial)</sup>
>
> If the cascaded value of a property is the revert keyword, the behavior depends on the cascade origin to which the declaration belongs:
>
> - user-agent origin
>   Equivalent to unset.
> - user origin
>   Rolls back the cascaded value to the user-agent level, so that the specified value is calculated as if no author-origin or user-origin rules were specified for this property on this element.
> - author origin
>   Rolls back the cascaded value to the user level, so that the specified value is calculated as if no author-origin rules were specified for this property on this element. For the purpose of revert, this origin includes the Animation origin.

```css
html body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html body ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

article .rich-text ul {
  padding: revert;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>項目1</li>
  <li>項目2</li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li>項目1</li>
  <li>項目2</li>
</ol>

<article>
  <div class="rich-text">
    <ul>
      <li>項目1</li>
      <li>項目2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>
```

---

最終的な SCSS は次のようになります。

**`base.scss`**

```
html {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

**`article.scss`**

```
article {
  .rich-text {
    ul {
      padding: revert;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: supa様　今回はsupa様の方法で解決できました。大変助かりました。ソースまで提示していただき、ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

初めまして。
結論から申し上げますと、既に追加したCSSのプロパティを削除する方法はありません。

まず初めに理解をしていただきたいのは、
CSSの初期化というのはChromeやFirefoxなどのブラウザ間での差異を無くすため作業です。

CSSは仕組み上、削除は出来ないですが、色々やり方は工夫できます。
・クラス名にCSSを指定する
・後から読み込むファイルでCSSを上書きする

Comment: masaru514様　まだまだcss触りたてでしたので大変勉強になりました。ご回答大変助かりました。ありがとうございました！